# Prove that $P(A \oplus B)= P(A) + P(B) -2P(A \cap B)$ is true.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that, for the probability space $(\Omega, P)$, $P(A \oplus B)= P(A) + P(B) -2P(A \cap B)$ is true.

Here's my attempt:

$$P(A \oplus B)=P((A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c))=P(A \cap B^c)+P(B \cap A^c)-P((A \cap B^c) \cap (A^c \cap B))= P(A \cap B^c)+P(B \cap A^c)$$

But how do I continue on from here? I read that we can simplify $P(A \cap B^c)$ to $P(A) - P(A \cap B)$, but it didn't say what rule/lemma/axiom it was using, which is why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\cap B^{c})=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$ [because $P(A)=P(A\cap B^{c})+P(A\cap B)$]. Similarly $P(B\cap A^{c})=P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Add these two.